# Ignoring AWS Managed/Default KMS Keys When Listing All Keys?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

I wrote the function below:

```
    private List<KeyListEntry> getKeyListEntries(AWSKMS kms)
{
    ListKeysRequest listKeysRequest = new ListKeysRequest();
    List<KeyListEntry> kmsKeys = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean moreKeys = false;

    do
    {
        ListKeysResult listKeysResult = kms.listKeys(listKeysRequest);
        kmsKeys.addAll(listKeysResult.getKeys());
        moreKeys = listKeysResult.getNextMarker() != null && !listKeysResult.getNextMarker().equals("");
        listKeysRequest.setMarker(listKeysResult.getNextMarker());
    } while (moreKeys);

    return kmsKeys;
}
```

It builds a list of all KMS keys in my account. The 'moreKeys' flag is to handle pagination of the response. Elsewhere on this list, I am calling:

```
kms.listResourceTags
```

so I can determine the tags on each individual key and perform an action accordingly. My problem is, I am usually at some point hitting the default master keys, for ACM and etc.

These policies for default keys do not allow the root account to do `kms:ListResourceTags`, and I cannot modify them to change that. Is there a simple way for me to filter out as I am building the list so I can ignore any AWS default KMS keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being an Amazon bug! I raised a case and the policy was fixed by the ACM team on the default key.